# How can I find the end of a dead wire that is not attached to a switch?

Tags: garage, light, light-bulb

I have a shop light in a garage but I can’t find a switch for it.

Leads me to believe it’s a dead wire not connected to anything.

I need to find the other end. I just don’t know where the shop light wire goes.

Thanks in advance

Comment: All lights have a switch.  Some might use a breaker for the switch or a string on the light.  If there is a wall switch 90% of the time it will be beside a door, maybe behind all the junk piled up there.  Should be a hole in the light housing if a pull string was used and is now broken.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.